# How can i see the background image behinde the inpute text in html?

Tags: html, css

I try to program a site in an HTML form and I need to see my background image behind the input text for example for search.
what can I do?
I try to set image background but when I add an input text it is white and I can't see bg image behind that
[image: Something like this]

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
    body {
    background-image: url(example url}#weap{display:inline;}

  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrap">
   <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="What're we looking for ?">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `opacity` to your search field. For example:

```
#search{
  opacity: .7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try styling it like this:

```
input {
   opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Reduce opacity of input field, so that the background image will get visible through the input field,
in your case use below code

#search{
   opacity:0.5;
   outline: none;
   webkit-appearance: none;
}

Here is the reference for learning more about Opacity attribute:
[link]:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#search{
position: relative;
z-index: 999999;
opacity: 0.3;
}
```